# What's the origin of the word "nachos"?

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown, spanish

Just like it says on the tin! Looking for root words or early usages, ideally "first usage" or an unambiguous etymological origin.

Comment: What did your research find???

Comment: Basically nothing. To paraphrase: 'It's used in America, it's origins are Mexican" & that's about it.

Comment: You didn't look very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not well known fact is that Google has an excellent dictionary. To use it you simply type `define word` and search. Usually you will be able to see word history, usage graphs and more.

Using this technique I found:

> Perhaps from Mexican Spanish Nacho, nickname for Ignacio, given name
>   of the chef credited with creation of the dish. An alternative
>   derivation is from Spanish nacho ‘flat-nosed.’

Comment: Further, if you type "etymology nacho" into Google you will get a wealth of information.

Comment: @HotLicks +1 [This](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/word-stories/nachos-anyone/) popped out of that search.